# wget not converting links that start with //

Tags: wget

If I have a `<script>` tag in an html file that is like so:

```
 <script src="//cdn.website.net/js/file.min.js"></script>
```

Convert links will change it to:

```
<script src="http://cdn.website.net/js/file.min.js"></script>
```

Is there anyway to make it actually download the file and fix the links for offline use?

My command is:

```
wget 
 --no-clobber 
 --convert-links
 --random-wait 
 --ignore-tags=img 
 -r 
 -p 
 -E 
 -e robots=off 
 -U mozilla 
 http://website.com
```

Comment: `//cdn.website.net` is not a URL.  It doesn't specify a protocol.  `http` tells it to go to port 80.  Where do you expect wget to actually get things at `//cdn.website.net`  from?  wget has no choice but to guess what you mean.  Do you mean an NT/SMB style share of `\\cdn.website.net` ??

Comment: If you are trying to do what I think, try `file://///cdn.website.net/js/file.min.js`  .. yes, stupid I know.. I didn't invent it.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581445/are-protocol-relative-urls-relative-urls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265762/scheme-relative-url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529790/are-there-cases-where-protocol-relative-urls-is-preferred-over-https